# Display top most, second most and other languages in one query along with their count

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have locales tables, users table, brands table. Below is their schema

> **locales**`: local_id, locale, country, language`
>
> **users**: `user_id,  userID, handle, friendly, created, firstname, middle, lastname, followers, sex, locale, pic
>
> **brands:** brands_id, friendly, short ,followers, created, location, brandID, handle, url, pic, utcOffset, posts, engagements, engagedUser

I need to get users who are in top most language, second highest language and other languages(top - second) for a brand.

I can get top two languages as :

```
SELECT l.language, count( l.language ) as 'top'FROM users u, locales l, brands b WHERE u.locale = l.locale AND b.handle = 'ford' GROUP BY l.language ORDER BY count( l.language ) DESC limit 0,2
```

I have joined users table, locales table and brands table.

What I need to do is get ****'top most language'****, **'second most language'** and **'other'** languages.

Also I need to calculate 'Top Language %' i.e top language/total language, 'second language %' and 'other %. One thing here to notice is, all this should be done in one single query. I appreciate your help. I am very badly stuck on this one. Thanks!

Comment: while i dont assert that single-query is impossible, i definitely wonder on *why-single* ? perhaps a stored procedure can be close to single-call-from-app.

Comment: @inquisitive I am not accustomed to stored procedure. I be learning it meanwhile. If it's possible for you to help with stored procedure, then please post here.

Comment: guys even if you can't figure it out in single query, please post, so I can have insights